# When did Undefined Behavior in C jump the causality barrier

Tags: c, history, undefined-behavior

Some hyper-modern C compilers will infer that if a program will invoke Undefined Behavior when given certain inputs, such inputs will never be received.  Consequently, any code which would be irrelevant unless such inputs are received may be eliminated.

As a simple example, given:

```
void foo(uint32_t);

uint32_t rotateleft(uint_t value, uint32_t amount)
{
  return (value << amount) | (value >> (32-amount));
}

uint32_t blah(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
  if (y != 0) foo(y);
  return rotateleft(x,y);
}
```

a compiler may infer that because evaluation of `value >> (32-amount)` will yield Undefined Behavior when `amount` is zero, function `blah` will never be called with `y` equal to zero; the call to `foo` can thus be made unconditional.

From what I can tell, this philosophy seems to have caught hold sometime around 2010.  The earliest evidence I've seen of its roots goes back to 2009, and it's been enshrined in the C11 standard which explicitly states that if Undefined Behavior occurs at any point in a program's execution, the behavior of the entire program retroactively becomes undefined.

Was the notion that compilers should attempt to use Undefined Behavior to justify reverse-causal optimizations (i.e. the Undefined Behavior in the `rotateleft` function should cause the compiler to assume that `blah` must have been called with a non-zero `y`, whether or not anything would ever cause `y` to hold a non-zero value) seriously advocated prior to 2009?  When was such a thing first seriously proposed as an optimization technique?

[Addendum]

Some compilers have, even in the 20th Century, included options to enable certain kinds of inferences about loops and the values computed therein.  For example, given

```
int i; int total=0;
for (i=n; i>=0; i--)
{
  doSomething();
  total += i*1000;
}
```

a compiler, even without the optional inferences, might rewrite it as:

```
int i; int total=0; int x1000;
for (i=n, x1000=n*1000; i>0; i--, x1000-=1000)
{
  doSomething();
  total += x1000;
}
```

since the behavior of that code would precisely match the original, *even if the compiler specified that `int` values always wrap in mod-65536 two's-complement fashion*.  The additional-inference option would let the compiler recognize that since `i` and `x1000` should cross zero at the same time, the former variable can be eliminated:

```
int total=0; int x1000;
for (x1000=n*1000; x1000 > 0; x1000-=1000)
{
  doSomething();
  total += x1000;
}
```

On a system where `int` values wrapped mod 65536, an attempt to run either of the first two loops with `n` equal to 33 would result in `doSomething()` being invoked 33 times.  The last loop, by contrast, wouldn't invoke `doSomething()` at all, even though the first invocation of `doSomething()` would have preceded any arithmetic overflow.  Such a behavior might be considered "non-causal", but the effects are reasonably well constrained and there many cases where the behavior would be demonstrably harmless (in cases where a function is required to yield some value when given *any* input, but the value may be arbitrary if the input is invalid, having the loop finish faster when given an invalid value of `n` would actually be beneficial).  Further, compiler documentation tended to be apologetic for the fact that it would change the behavior of any programs--even those that engaged in UB.

I'm interested in when compiler writers' attitudes changed away from the idea that platforms should when practical document some usable behavioral constraints even in cases not mandated by the Standard, to the idea that any constructs which would rely upon any behaviors not mandated by the Standard should be branded illegitimate even if on most existing compilers it would work as well or better than any strictly-compliant code meeting the same requirements (often allowing optimizations which would not be possible in strictly-compliant code).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26565/discussion-on-question-by-supercat-when-did-undefined-behavior-in-c-jump-the-cau).

Comment: @rwong: I don't see how that even violates the laws of time, much less causality.  If illegitimate static casts terminated program execution (hardly an obscure execution model), and if the build model were such that no additional classes could be defined after linking, then no input to the program could cause `shape->Is2D()` to be invoked on an object that was not derived from `Shape2D`.  There is a *huge* difference between optimizing out code which would only be relevant if a critical Undefined Behavior has *already happened* versus code which would only be relevant in cases where...

Comment: ...there are no downstream execution paths that don't invoke some form of Undefined Behavior.  While the definition of "critical undefined behavior" given in (IIRC) Annex L is a bit vague, an implementation might reasonably implement static casting and virtual dispatch such that the indicated code would jump to an arbitrary address (it's critical UB).  For it to always jump to `Shape2D::Is­2D` is actually better than the program deserves.

Comment: @rwong: Exactly, and before 2009 that was the case.  One benefit of leaving things undefined was that different applications have different requirements with regard to how they should handle invalid inputs, and different platforms' natural behaviors with invalid inputs will fit naturally with different application requirements.  For some applications it is necessary that no seemingly-valid output will be produced unless an algorithm executes successfully (but may crash given invalid input); others must produce garbage output when given garbage input (but must not crash).

Comment: If an application of the former type was run on an implementation which would hardware-trap integer overflows, the application could meet its requirements without any overflow-checking of its own.  If an application of the latter type was run on an implementation where overflows would yield results that met requirements, it could likewise meet requirements without any overflow checking of its own.  For the Standard to impose either form of overflow behavior would have meant that all applications of the other type would need manual overflow checking, and...

Comment: ...if run on a platform whose natural behavior would have met their requirements, might very well end up receiving useless compiler-generated overflow handling as well; as a consolation, though, it would remove the need for manual overflow handling in applications of the favored type which were run on the disfavored platform.  A useful way to improve portability without such problems would have been to provide a means by which programmers could specify "I need overflows to be handled X way", which would only require compilers to include overflow handling when the program needed...

Comment: ...something other than their platforms' natural behavior, and would avoid in many cases avoid the need for programmers to use manual overflow handling at all.  Major win.  Unfortunately, compilers are going in the opposite direction.  If a function's sole requirements are (1) compute `x+y` when representable as `int` (2) don't launch nuclear missiles when `x+y` is not representable as `int`, the amount of code (both source and, on some platforms, executable) required to meet requirement #2 may exceed that required for #1.

Comment: @rwong: I've read that appendix, but unfortunately it doesn't really make clear what can and cannot happen in various cases.  For example, I don't think anything specifies whether `int arr[256]; int16_t x; int16_t y=x & 255; arr[y]=123;` would be required to set `y` to a value in the range 0..255 and thus ensure that `arr[y]` accessed a legitimate array element, or whether `x & 255` would be a "fully" indeterminate value, such that the access of `arr[y]` would invoke critical UB.

Comment: @rwong: As for the duplicate, the intention of my question was to ask when *in human history* the normative interpretation of Undefined Behavior with regard to e.g. overflow shifted from "If a platform's natural behavior would allow an application to satisfy its requirements without error checking, having the standard mandate any contrary behavior may increase the complexity of the source code, executable code, and compiler code necessary to have a program meet requirements, so the Standard should instead let the platform do what it does best" to "Compilers should assume that programmers...

Comment: ...will always include code to prevent overflows in any cases where they don't want to launch nuclear missiles."  Historically, given the specification "write a function which, given two arguments of type 'int', returns the product if it's representable as 'int', or else either terminates the program or returns an arbitrary number", `int prod(int x, int y) {return x*y;}` would have sufficed.  Complying with "don't launch nukes" in strictly-compliant fashion, however, would require code that's harder to read and would almost certainly run much slower on many platforms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27027/discussion-between-rwong-and-supercat).

Answer (score 6):

Undefined behavior is used in situations where it is not feasible for the spec to specify the behavior, and it has always been written to allow absolutely any behavior possible.

The extremely ultra-loose rules for UB are helpful when you think about what a spec conforming compiler must go through.  You may have sufficient compiling horsepower to emit an error when you do some bad UB in one case, but add a few layers of recursion and now the best you can do is a warning.  The spec has no concept of "warnings," so if the spec had given a behavior, it would have to be "an error."

The reason we see more and more side effects of this is the push for optimization.  Writing a spec conforming optimizer is hard.  Writing a spec conforming optimizer which also happens to do a remarkably good job guessing what you intended when you went outside the spec is brutal.  It is much easier on the compilers if they get to assume UB means UB.

This is especially true for gcc, which tries to support many many instruction sets with the same compiler.  It is far easier to let UB yield UB behaviors than it is to try to grapple with all the ways every single UB code could go wrong on every platform, and factor it into the early phrases of the optimizer.

Comment: The reason C got its reputation for speed is that programmers who knew that even in some cases where the Standard imposed no requirements the behavior of their platform would satisfy their requirements could make use of such behavior.  If a platform guarantees that `x-y > z` will arbitrarily yield 0 or 1 when `x-y` is not representable as "int", such a platform will have more optimization opportunities than a platform which requires the expression to be written as either `UINT_MAX/2+1+x+y > UINT_MAX/2+1+z` or `(long long)x+y > z`.

Comment: Prior to roughly 2009, a typical interpretation of many forms of UB would be e.g. "Even if executing a shift-right-by-N instruction on the target CPU could stall the bus for several minutes with interrupt disabled when N is -1 [I've heard of such a CPU], a compiler may pass any N to the shift-right-by-N instruction without validation, or mask N with 31, or arbitrarily choose among those options".  In cases where any of the above behaviors would meet requirements, programmers didn't need to waste time (theirs or the machine's) preventing them from occurring. What prompted the change?

Comment: @supercat I would say that, even in 2015, a "typical" interpretation of UB would be similarly benign.  The problem is not the typical case of UB, its the unusual cases.  I'd say 95-98% of UB I have accidentally written "worked as intended."  It's the remaining 2-5% where you can't understand why the UB got so out of hand until you have spent 3 years digging deep in the bowels of gcc's optimizer to realize that it actually was just as outlandish of a case as they thought... it just looked easy at first.

Comment: An excellent example I ran into was a One Definition Rule (ODR) violation I wrote by accident, naming two classes the same thing, and getting severe stack bashing when I called one function and it ran the other.  It seems reasonable to say "why didn't you just use the nearest class name, or at least warn me," until you understand how the linker resolves naming issues.  There simply was no "good" behavior option available unless they put massive amounts of extra code in the compiler to catch it.

Comment: Linker technology is generally horrible, but there are substantial chicken-and-egg barriers to improving it.  Otherwise, what I think is needed is for C to standardize a set of portability/optimization typedefs and macros such that existing compilers *which support the behaviors implied thereby* could support the new standard merely by adding a header file, and code wishing to use the new features could be used with older compilers that supported the behaviors merely by including a "compatibility" header file, but compilers would then be able to achieve much better optimizations...

Comment: @supercat I have actually been tempted to suggest Boost is that library.  It's not official, but it has a tendency to turn official over time.

Comment: ...without breaking anything because they'd know when they needed to preserve old behaviors that were shared by many compilers though not mandated by the Standard, and when looser behavior would be acceptable.  For example, I'd like to see types like `wrap32_t` defined essentially as behaving the way `uint32_t` behaves *on a platform where some values it holds are not representable as `int`*, and `unum32_t` defined as behaving more like the way `uint32_t` behaves *on a platform where all its values are representable as `int`.*

Comment: Every platform which defines `uint32_t` could define either `wrap32_t` or `unum32_t` as an alias to it (depending upon the size of `int`); platforms where `int` is 64 bits could support `uwrap32_t` (and should be encouraged to do so) but the behavior would be unlike that of any standard-defined type *on 64-bit platforms* [the behavior would not be "new", however, since it would go back to days before there *were* 64-bit platfomrs].

Comment: C doesn't, and can't, support anything equivalent to Boost.  I'd like to see a standard for a language whose normal programming paradigms were those of C rather than C++, but which supported things like overloading of static operators and functions [static only so as to avoid name-mangling issues], since that would make it possible to define types whose behavior matches those of types from almost any other machine, though such a thing would probably have been more useful 15 years ago than today.  Having defined norms for things like `wrap32_t`, however, would ease porting of 32-bit code to 64.

Comment: I'd also suggest types like `xuint16_t`, `ouint16_t`, and `oint16_t` to allow many optimizations that are presently not possible.  After `xuint16_t x = 0x12345678;` any read of `x` could independently yield 0x12345678 & (any value | 65535);`, and after `oint16_t y=0x12345; ouint16_t z = 0x12345;` any read of `y` or `z` could yield any value congruent to 0x2345 mod 65536.  Presently on machines where `int` is larger than 16 bits, the statements using unsigned types would have rigidly-defined behavior, and those using signed type would have Implementation-Defined behavior which...

Comment: ...for most implementations essentially has to wrap in two's-complement fashion.  The types as I would define them would be much more amenable to optimization, but unlike the useless `fastN_t` their storage format would be defined as compatible with `uint16_t`.

Comment: @supercat It sounds like you are looking for a language which does not follow the old adage "A language is not complete when you are done putting every feature in, it is complete when you have taken everything you can out."  C is definitely in the old crowd of languages, which tries to minimize how many things it need to define in order to work.

Comment: C is used for enough different purposes with contradictory requirements that no single dialect should try to serve them all.  One of the reasons it has thrived historically is that compilers targeting different markets have historically implemented dialects which were suitable for such markets.  The existence of many different dialects makes migration of code between platforms difficult, but the remedy is not to suggest that programmers should refrain from exploiting useful dialect-specific features, but rather that they should indicate in "machine-readable" fashion when they are doing so.

Comment: @supercat I think the challenge is that what you are looking for is contradictory to the goal of C, which is portability.  For example, C has survived processor bit widths of 8, 16, 31, 64, 128, 7, 14, etc.  Not even always powers of 2.  It has survived big endian, little endian, the many flavors of middle endian.  It does not specify IEEE-754 floats.  The more language features it adds directly to the specification, the more the specification bloats.  There's a reason it wasn't until the late 2000's that C defined a char to be 1 byte.

Comment: An example of a system that has gone the way you mention is openGL, with their extension mechanism.  The result was tremendously unreadable code as individuals had to write 5 or 6 versions of the code for different vendor's APIs, each slightly different enough in some nuance to require a special feature.  For fun, I also recommend reading the HDF-5 value type specification.  Its AMAZING just how many "non standard" numeric representations there are.

Comment: If the Standard were to specify that platforms may only implement `wrap32_t` when they can make it behave the way an `uint32_t` would work on a platform where `unsigned int` is 32 bits, then code which uses that type could only work on compilers that can provide a type with that functionality.  On the other hand, code which relies upon such functionality and expects to receive it from type `uint32_t` will only work on compilers which provide such functionality *and* define `int` to be 32 bits or smaller.  Allowing for the possibility of a 64-bit compiler implementing `wrap32_t`...

Comment: @supercat Yes they can.  However, how many thousands of these "if only..." cases are there?  You've seen a few.  Personally, I've seen at least a few hundred.  You can see how rapidly code bloat could grow.  For an example of where it has grown, take a look at C++11's `memory_order_consume`.  They probably added 10-20 pages of wording for that memory order.  As you say, platforms that don't implement it are free to fall back on other orders, like `memory_order_acquire`.  However, how much spec-writing time had to be spent to support the needs of a subgroup.

Comment: Meanwhile, Concepts-lite, which is a highly anticipated set of features, couldn't make it into C++11 because there wasn't enough time to iron it out

Comment: What stops you from defining your own `wrap32_t` in your own library, which does exactly what you want?

Comment: I believe that in many cases amount of effort required to make e.g. a 64-bit compiler support a `wrap32_t`, and make code which people would like to use with that compiler use `wrap32_t` anyplace 32-bit unsigned wrapping behavior might be necessary, would be far less than the amount of effort required to hand-inspect all operations involving `uint32_t` variables and rewrite any code which relies upon wrapping behavior; I also believe the number of new bugs stemming from slightly-incorrect rewrites would be far less.  Such a thing can't happen if everyone defines their own `wrap32_t`.  Also...

Comment: ...if different libraries each provide their own definitions for `wrap32_t`, are pointers to those types going to be compatible?  If there is a single standardized `wrap32_t` type, and pointers to it are defined as being compatible with pointers to `uint32_t` (even when the former is implemented as a compiler intrinsic), compatibility would be guaranteed.  While it would probably be possible to define thousands of behaviors that someone somewhere might be relying upon, recognizing even a dozen of the most common variations would be much more useful than recognizing zero.

Comment: Finally, consider that if the Standard indicates exactly what things a `wrap32_t` must guarantee, and what things it doesn't guarantee, then as a programmer even if I'd prefer a type which guarantees things that `wrap32_t` doesn't, I can write my code to confirm to the guarantees of `wrap32_t` and someone who later wants to port my code will know that if I've done my job my code should work on any compiler which upholds the Standard's guarantees.  If I'd used my own type, it would be much harder for someone porting my code to a future 64-bit compiler which supports a type similar to my...

Comment: ...proposed `wrap32_t`, whether changing that type to the compiler's type would make the code work on the new platform.

Comment: @supercat I recommend going into making your own languages.  It's good fun, and you develop an appreciation for why languages choose to do some things and not others.  The way specs are designed makes a lot more sense after you've had to maintain a language for a few years.  I, personally, cannot imagine making language decisions that need to be valid for 30 or 40 years.  Those people are extrordinary!

Comment: The historical reason the C family of dialects has thrived is that compiler vendors who saw that they could easily provide in their dialects useful semantics beyond the minimums dictated by the Standard, generally did so.  Given `int x; unsigned int y; ... x<<=1; y>>=1;` the compilers I've seen for platforms whose only right-shifting instructions copy carry into the MSB will generate a "clear-carry" instruction even though performing `x<<=1` when `x` is positive (which it must be in a strictly-conforming program) would clear the carry flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26559/discussion-between-cort-ammon-and-supercat).

Comment: @CortAmmon: C *always* defined `char` to be one byte, no exceptions. It being at least 8 bits wasn't a guarantee (much?) before the ANSI-standard though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I can't imagine any plausible C dialect where `char` wasn't at least 7 bits, given that every character in the C source-code character set is required to map to a distinct `char` value and 64 wouldn't be enough to accommodate anything other than letters, numbers, newline, and space.

Comment: I'm not aware of any C compiler variant ever having had less than 7 bits per byte either. Not sure what your point is though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I was merely responding to your claim that `char` wasn't guaranteed to be 8 bits prior to ANSI by observing that while machines might have existed which could access data in chunks smaller than 8 bits, the smallest `char` that could ever have been legal, even before ANSI, would have been 7 bits.

Answer (score 4):

"Undefined behaviour might cause the compiler to rewrite code" has happened for a long time, in loop optimisations.

Take a loop (a and b are pointer to double, for example)

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) a [i] = b [i];
```

We increment an int, we copy an array element, we compare with a limit. An optimising compiler first removes the indexing:

```
double* tmp1 = a;
double* tmp2 = b;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) *tmp1++ = *tmp2++;
```

We remove the case n <= 0:

```
i = 0;
if (n > 0) {
    double* tmp1 = a;
    double* tmp2 = b;
    for (; i < n; ++i) *tmp1++ = *tmp2++;
}
```

Now we eliminate the variable i:

```
i = 0;
if (n > 0) {
    double* tmp1 = a;
    double* tmp2 = b;
    double* limit = tmp1 + n;
    for (; tmp1 != limit; tmp1++, tmp2++) *tmp1 = *tmp2;
    i = n;
}
```

Now if n = 2^29 on a 32 bit system or 2^61 on a 64 bit system, on typical implementations we will have tmp1 == limit, and no code is executed. Now replace the assignment with something that takes a long time so that the original code will never run into the inevitable crash because it takes too long, and the compiler has changed the code.

Comment: If neither pointer is volatile, I wouldn't consider that a rewrite of the code.  Compilers have for a long time been allowed to resequence writes to non-`volatile` pointers, so behavior in the case where `n` is so large that pointers would wrap would be equivalent to having an out-of-bounds store clobber a temporary storage location holding `i` before anything else happens.  If `a` or `b` were volatile, the platform documented that volatile accesses generate physical load/store operations in the sequence requested, and it the platform defines any means via which such requests...

Comment: ...could deterministically affect program execution, then I would argue that a compiler should refrain from the indicated optimizations (though I'll readily acknowledge that some might not have been programmed to prevent such optimizations unless `i` was also made volatile).  That would be a pretty rare behavioral corner case, though.  If `a` and `b` are non-volatile, I'd suggest that there would be no *plausible intended meaning* for what the code should do if `n` is so large as to overwrite all of memory.  By contrast, many other forms of UB have plausible intended meanings.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I can think of situations where assumptions about the laws of integer arithmetic could cause loops to terminate prematurely before any UB occurs and without the a loop doing any illegitimate address computations.  In FORTRAN, there's a clear distinction between loop control variables and other variables, but C lacks that distinction, which is unfortunate since requiring programmers to always prevent overflow on loop control variables would be far less of an impediment to efficient coding than having to prevent overflow anywhere.

Comment: I wonder how language rules could best be written so that code which would be happy with a range of behaviors in case of overflow could say that, without impeding genuinely useful optimizations?  There are many cases where code must produce strictly-defined output given valid input, but loosely-defined output when given invalid input.  E.g. suppose a programmer who would be inclined to write `if (x-y>z) do_something()`;` doesn't care whether `do_something` executes in case of overflow, provided the overflow has no other effect.  Is there any way to rewrite the above which will not...

Comment: ...generate needlessly-inefficient code on at least some platforms (compared with what those platforms could generate if given a free choice of whether or not to invoke `do_something`)?  Even if loop optimizations were forbidden from yielding behavior inconsistent with a loose overflow model, programmers could write code in such a way as to allow compilers to generate optimal code.  Is there any way to work around inefficiencies compelled by an "avoid overflow at all costs" model?

Comment: I figured out why modern behavior bothers me more than loop transforms.  In cases where Undefined Behavior results from platform-specific limitations (like the range of integers) it is not "astonishing" for platforms to go beyond those limitations (e.g. given `long l2=i1+i2+l3;` it would not be astonishing for a compiler to produce an arithmetically-correct result even if `i1+i2` overflows).  If a compiler optimizes `for (i=n; i>0; i--) total+=i*30000;} to {for (i=n*30000; i>0; i-=30000) total+=i;` such an optimization would have no effect on program behavior if the compiler...

Comment: ...non-astonishingly performed all operations in arithmetically-correct fashion.  While allowing a compiler to make transformations which rely upon one execution model without requiring that code generation use the same execution model may have somewhat astonishing consequences, I would consider that less astonishing than transformations which would not be semantics-preserving under any execution model where input could come from "untrustworthy" sources.

Answer (score 3):

It has always been the case in C and C++ that as a result of undefined behaviour, *anything* can happen. Therefore it has also always been the case that a compiler can make the assumption that your code doesn't invoke undefined behaviour: Either there is no undefined behaviour in your code, then the assumption was correct. Or there is undefined behaviour in your code, then whatever happens as a result of the incorrect assumption is covered by "*anything* can happen".

If you look at the "restrict" feature in C, the whole point of the feature is that the compiler can assume there is no undefined behaviour, so there we reached the point where the compiler not only *may* but actually *should* assume there is no undefined behaviour.

In the example that you give, the assembler instructions usually used on x86 based computers to implement left or right shift will shift by 0 bits if the shift count is 32 for 32 bit code or 64 for 64 bit code. This will in most practical cases lead to undesirable results (and results that are not the same as on ARM or PowerPC, for example), so the compiler is quite justified to assume that this kind of undefined behaviour doesn't happen. You could change your code to

```
uint32_t rotateleft(uint_t value, uint32_t amount)
{
   return amount == 0 ? value : (value << amount) | (value >> (32-amount));
}
```

and suggest to the gcc or Clang developers that on most processors the "amount == 0" code should be removed by the compiler, because the assembler code generated for the shift code will produce the same result as value when amount == 0.

Comment: I can think of very few platforms where an implementation of `x>>y` [for unsigned `x`] that would work when variable `y` held any value from 0 to 31, and did something other than yield 0 or `x>>(y & 31)` for other values, could be as efficient as one which did something else; I know of no platform where guaranteeing that no action other than one of the above would occur would add significant cost.  The idea that programmers should use some more complicated formulation in code that would never have to be run on obscure machines would have been viewed as absurd.

Comment: My question is when did things shift from "x>>32` might arbitrarily yield `x` or `0`, or might trap on some obscure platforms" to "`x>>32` might cause the compiler to rewrite the meaning of other code"?  The earliest evidence I can find is from 2009, but I'm curious if earlier evidence exists.

Comment: @Deduplicator: My replacement works perfectly fine for values that make sense, that is 0 <= amount < 32. And whether your (value >> 32 - amount) is correct or not, I don't care, but leaving the parentheses out is as bad as a bug.

Comment: Didn't see the restriction to `0<=amount && amount<32`. Whether bigger/smaller values make sense? I thought whether they do is part of the question. And not using parentheses in the face of bit-ops is probably a bad idea, sure, but certainly not a bug.

Comment: @Deduplicator this is because [some CPUs natively implement the shift operator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate) as `(y mod 32)` for 32-bit `x` and `(y mod 64)` for 64-bit `x`. Note that it is relatively easy to emit code that will achieve uniform behavior across all CPU architectures - by masking the shift amount. This usually takes one extra instruction. But alas ...

Comment: @rwong: I'm speaking about the contract for that function, not the resulting object-code...

Comment: @rwong: On the INMOS Transputer, computing `x << -1` would stall the bus for 4294967296 cycles, and I doubt it was the first machine were that could happen.  While it might have been possible for the Standard to say that compilers may arbitrarily mod-reduce the shift amount to any multiple of the word size and/or any power-of-two value larger than the word size, and say that values which are negative or excessively large may cause problems, such excessive detail wouldn't matter if not for an attitude compiler writers seem to have acquired around 2009.

Comment: @rwong: Another thing to consider is that if code needs to compute `y > 31 ? 0 : x << y`, and `y` values will always be within a range where a processor's shift-left instruction will yield that in an acceptable time frame [e.g. most ARM processors will do a single-cycle instruction to compute `(y & 255) > 31 ? 0 : x << (y & 31)`], the most useful thing the compiler can do is simply have `x << y` generate the shift instruction.

Answer (score -1):

This is because there is a bug in your code:

```
uint32_t blah(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    if (y != 0) 
    {
        foo(y);
        return x; ////// missing return here //////
    }
    return rotateleft(x, y);
}
```

In other words, it only jumps the causality barrier if the compiler sees that, given certain inputs, you are invoking undefined behavior *beyond doubt*.

By returning right before the invocation of undefined behavior, you tell the compiler that you are consciously preventing that undefined behavior from executing, and the compiler acknowledges that.

In other words, when you have a compiler that tries to enforce the specification in a very strict way, you have to implement every possible argument validation in your code. Furthermore, these validation must occur before the invocation of the said undefined behavior.

**Wait! And there is more!**

Now, with compilers doing these super-crazy yet super-logical things, it is your imperative to tell the compiler that a function isn't supposed to continue execution. Thus, the `noreturn` keyword on the `foo()` function **now becomes mandatory**.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the question.

Comment: @Deduplicator Had that not been the question, this question should have been closed for being opinion-based (open debate). Effectively it is second-guessing the motivations of the C and C++ committees and that of the compiler vendor/writers.

Comment: It's a question about historic interpretation, use and rationale of UB in the C language, not restricted to the standard and the committee. Second-guessing the committees? Not so.

Comment: That said, I agree that it is extremely error-prone, and the effective outcome of such designer decisions is that "now nobody, not even experienced professionals, can write valid C code", and finally get everyone move away from C and toward safer languages.

Comment: @rwong: C is still the best language for many kinds of systems-programming tasks where most forms of Undefined Behavior have traditionally been mapped to "generate the instruction to the indicated operation on the indicated values without regard for the validity of the operands and let the underlying hardware do as it will".  If code will only be meaningful on a processor where the result of `x>>=y` is equivalent to `for (int i=0; i<(y & 255); x>>=1` but executes in two cycles for any `y`, I'd consider `x>>y` more readable than `(y & 224) ? 0 : x >> (y & 31)`, even if an optimizer could...

Comment: ...recognize that the latter should only take one instruction.  I don't know if the hyper-modernists are desperately trying to make C competitive in fields where it's been replaced, but they're undermining its utility in the only field where it's king, and are from what I can tell making useful optimizations harder rather than easier.

Comment: The C language is going to endure a lifecycle of [Wittgenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein). (Or maybe the hyper-modernists are going to.)

Comment: @rwong: With regard for my question, I wrote it in such a fashion that it should be answerable.  Some recent papers have advocated the kind of "optimization" I describe and have been taken seriously, but presumably none did so prior to the invention of C.  Consequently, someone must have advocated such behavior and been taken seriously before anyone else did so.  Whether or not it is possible to prove that any documented advocacy of such behavior is the first, it would be likely that any advocacy of which no evidence is found probably wasn't taken too seriously.

Comment: @rwong: The code in the question was written to perform an action which on the vast majority of compilers would historically have had one of two behaviors, both of which would end up yielding the same effect.  Someone writing such code might reasonably have figured "If someone ever needs to run this code on a processor where `x>>32` does something other than yielding x or yielding zero, this code won't work, but there's no plausible reason to believe such a thing might occur".

Comment: @rwong: I don't quite understand your historical illusion; can you offer a brief summary?  Otherwise, I wonder if your view that people should move away from C is shared by the current maintainers of the Standard.  It would explain a lot.

Comment: Recently C is getting a lot of influence from C++, and C++ from C#, Haskell, Ocaml and other languages. So, C is not the old C anymore. Meanwhile, [Barr](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/Embedded-C-Quiz) might be upholding a view of C that is closer to what people had remembered from the earlier days.

Comment: @rwong: I just tried that embedded C quiz.  I'm not sure why `(60 * 60 * 24 * 365UL)` is in any practical sense more portable than `(60 * 60 * 24 * 365)` since very few machines can represent 86400 as an `int` without overflow without also being able to represent 31536000.  A proper portable way to write it would have been `(60 * 60 * 24L * 365)` but that wasn't a choice.

Comment: @ago: Actually, on a system with 24 bit int the first would succeed and the second would fail. In embeddeed systems, anything goes. Or a lot goes; i can remember one where int = 32 bit, and long = 40 bit which is the only system I ever saw where long is a lot less efficient than int32_t.

Comment: @gnasher729: I've used systems with 16-bit `char`, but never 24-bit `int`.  I guess on such a system the first form would be "more" portable than the second, though I'd suggest the first form of the code is really targeting itself only toward systems where `int` is 17-25 bits, the second form toward systems where `int` is 26 bits or larger, and the non-listed choice `(60*60*24L*365)` as targeting systems with any legal size `int` that might be 25 bits or smaller.